# Is my proof valid? Prove that if a, b, and c are real numbers and a ≠ 0, then there is a unique solution for x of the equation ax + b = c.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

**I know this is painfully basic for some of you, but please do help me, proof writing is very new to me. thanks**

We start with $ax+b=c.$

We obtain $ax=c-b$ by subtracting $b$ from both sizes of the equation.

Then, we get the following solution to the equation. $x=(c-b)/a$

Now we must prove that $x=(c-b)/a$ is a unique solution.

let $z$ be a solution to our equation.

We have $az+b=c$.

Because $ax+b=c$ and $az+b=c$ we get $ax+b=az+b$

Now we obtain $ax=az$ by subtracting $b$ from both sides.

Then, we divide by $a$ and obtain $x=z$.

Therefore, $x=(c-b)/a$ is a unique solution to our equation.

Comment: Yeah... sounds good.  A little more thorough then necessary but that's not a bad thing.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You might note that we can divide by $a$ since it is given that $a\ne0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect!

But it might help to note that the solution *must* be unique because every step *must* be true.  That is.

If $ax + b = c$ then it *MUST* be true that

$ax = c-b$.

And if $ax =c-b$ and $a\ne 0$ then it *MUST* be true that

$x =\frac {c-b}a$.

And if it *must* be true that $x = \frac {c-b}a$ then that is the only possible solution.

.....

Note a less direct way would be:

Claim:  $x = \frac {c-b}a$ is a solution.

Verify $a(\frac {c-b}a) + b=$

$(c-b) + b = c+(-b+b) =c + 0 =c$.

So it is a solution....

If you had done that (but why would you) then you *would* have to verify it is unique.

But by *SOLVING*  well, solving is *solving*.  It finds all and only all solutions.  So it would be unique.